# Get values for batch of keys without loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

I'm building dictionary in python from a table which is ~2Gb big. It includes ID and description. eg:

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| COG5157 | cell division cycle 73 |
| COG5153 | Lipase |
| COG5156 | complex subunit 10 |
| COG5151 | Transcription factor |

and I also have another file with IDs, which I would like to map on this table (to obtain description)
I have approximately 140000 IDs

I'm running it in python3 `for` loop, which is actually pretty slow (up to 90 minutes).

```
nogidsdict=nog_db.set_index('id')['description'].to_dict()
prof_db['description']=""
for i in range(len(prof_id)):
    try:
        prof_db.iloc[i,2]=nogidsdict[prof_id[i]]
    except:
        prof_db.iloc[i,2]='None'
```

Is it possible to obtain values from dictionary for batch of keys without looping? Do you have any suggestion how I could speed up this part of script?

Thank you in advance!